# Conditional mutate - creating a new variable with coalesce

Tags: r, dplyr, conditional-statements, tidyverse

I'm scraping data from a website and depending on the structure of the page. I have an inner join in my final table that either joins clean on WON and LOST variables or I need to perform a clean-up step to coalesce four variables into the WON and LOST.

My issue is that my code, as written, always assumes a dirty join (bolded mutates).

```
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `WON.x = coalesce(WON.x, WON.y)`.
Caused by error in `list2()`:
! object 'WON.x' not found
```

I believe the solution is that I need the two mutates to only run if there's a dirty join (i.e., WON and LOST become WON.x, WON.y, LOST.x, LOST.y).

I cannot figure this out and have tried various approaches using "matched", "across(any_of)" etc, but I cannot get it work. I think I'm getting mixed up in the syntax trying to include coalesce.

Any help appreciated  in how to mutate and coalesce like this only if certain other columns exist. Thanks.

````
final=inner_join(temp1,temp2, by="id") %>% 
    select(-any_of(c("DRAW.x", "DRAW.y"))) %>% 
    **mutate(WON.x = coalesce(WON.x,WON.y)) %>% 
    mutate(LOST.x =coalesce(LOST.x,LOST.y)) %>%** 
    select(-any_of(c("WON.y","LOST.y"))) %>% 
    rename(WON=WON.x, LOST=LOST.x)```
````

Comment: `if("WON.y" %in% names(final)){...}`

Comment: FYI, code blocks in StackExchange need the triple-backticks `\`\`\`` to be _on their own line_, as in `\`\`\`\n` with nothing else on the same line.

Comment: @MichaelDewar could you show me how I would write that into my code using pipes? (if that's possible)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not everything should be squeezed into a pipe.  I would do the following:

```
library(tidyverse)

## These two give a clean join:
temp1 <- tibble(id = 1:3,
                 WON= 5:7)
temp2 <- tibble(id = 1:3,
                 LOST = 3:5)

## These two give a dirty join:
temp1 <- tibble(id = 1:3,
                 WON = 5:7,
                 LOST = c(3L, NA, 5L))
temp2 <- tibble(id = 1:3,
                WON = c(NA, NA, 7L),
                LOST = 3:5)

final <- inner_join(temp1, temp2, by = "id")

if("WON.y" %in% names(final)){
    final <- final %>% 
        mutate(WON = coalesce(WON.x, WON.y),
               LOST = coalesce(LOST.x, LOST.y),
               .keep = "unused")
}
final
```

I honestly can't think of a clear way to do it directly in a pipe.  It is not a good idea to write an abstruse one-liner just to make it fit into a pipe.  Clear code is best even if you must interrupt a pipe.

If you insist, you could write a little function that becomes pipeable.  But then the reader must go off and find this other code that also isn't really in the pipe.

Comment: Thank you so much. This did it! Excellent advice re: the pipe. It's interesting I get so focused on having everything piped almost like horse blinders to the other ways of doing things. Thanks again!

Comment: I also have the same problem with pipe tunnel vision. :)